# Creating Custom Characters?

Tags: voxatron

So, with the release of Voxatron v0.1.6, you're supposedly able to create custom player character models now for use in the game.  But the whole system seems really complicated, and I, for one, have no idea where to begin.  How do I go about creating a new character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.lexaloffle.com/bbs/?tid=727) seems to explain (at least in part) what you are supposed to do.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjlmreSOmQo) is a guide to using the editor itself, although it doesn't specifically cover characters.

Comment: I was hoping to get the original author of that tutorial to repost it here, but it doesn't sound like he's interested.  +1 for linking to it.